How to workaround critical issue for keychain-swift library?
On the official github site for keychain-swift library there is a statement:

I have a simple class to decode and encode values from keychain:
class Keychain: Keychainable {
    private let keychain: KeychainSwift
    init(keychain: KeychainSwift) {
        self.keychain = keychain
    }

    func encode(value: String, forKey key: String) {
        keychain.set(value, forKey: key)
    }

    func decode(forKey key: String) -> String? {
        var returnValue: String?
        for _ in 1...3 {
            if let value = keychain.get(key) {
                returnValue = value
            } // ❌ my current non working workaround
        }
        return returnValue
    }

    func delete(forKey key: String) {
        keychain.delete(key)
    }
}

And I have another Devicer class where I use it:
class Devicer: Devicable {
    private let device: UIDevice
    private let keychain: Keychainable
    var deviceIdentifier: String {
        guard let identifier = keychain.decode(forKey: "did") else {
            let uuid = device.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
            keychain.encode(value: uuid, forKey: "did")
            return uuid
        }
        return identifier
    }
}

I need to keep ONE PERMANENT deviceId for all long live of the app on the device. But it changes from time to time. Every couple days decode returns nil, but it should not because there is a non nil value. Because it returns nil (it should not) then new deviceId is created and saved as deviceId.
How to create working workaround for it?

Yes, it is unrelated because doesnt solve the problem. Yes you are right, it is better version of the loop... however not important at all.

Note that there has never been an official, permanent device identifier. The keychain approach is often used, but it is not an official solution. You could possibly combine the keychain approach and the identifierForVendor. If you have to create a new deviceId for the same IDfV then you can associate the new deviceId with the old. Or you could even store the IDfV as the deviceId rather than a random value. Your exposure is then cases where the keychain value can't be read and the IDfV has changed, which is probably a very small number of cases

You could store deviceId not just in keychain, but also in the (say) file system (since there's nothing personal about identifierForVendor!.uuidString). Try reading from file system or UserDefaults first. If fails, check keychain. This minimizes the probability of the issue, if it's specific to keychain. Could be other things though (e.g. device starting ,and nothing ready yet, not even file system).
Also identifierForVendor!.uuidString is not truly permanent. If you want something permanent, best generate your own UUID and save it everywhere
